# GoogleNet-LSTM, cross entropy loss does not decrease

Tags: conv-neural-network, loss-functions, lstm, cross-entropy, torch

```
class googleNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim=512):
    super(googleNet, self).__init__()
    self.model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'googlenet', pretrained=True)

    #freeze paramters (trains faster and keeps weight values of ImageNet)
    for params in self.model.parameters():
      params.requires_grad = False

    #change last fully completerd layer
    self.model.fc = nn.Linear(self.model.fc.in_features, latent_dim)

  def forward(self, x):
    output = self.model(x)
    return output

class Lstm(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim = 512, hidden_size = 256, lstm_layers = 2, bidirectional = True):
    super(Lstm, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.lstm_layers = lstm_layers
    self.bidirectional = bidirectional
    self.Lstm = nn.LSTM(self.latent_dim, hidden_size=self.hidden_size, num_layers=self.lstm_layers, batch_first=True, bidirectional=self.bidirectional)
    self.hidden_state = None

  def reset_hidden_state(self):
    self.hidden_state = None

  def forward(self,x):
    output, self.hidden_state = self.Lstm(x, self.hidden_state)
    return output

class ConvLstm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, google, lstm, n_class = 10):
        super(ConvLstm, self).__init__()
        self.modela = google
        self.modelb = lstm
        self.output_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2 * self.modelb.hidden_size if self.modelb.bidirectional==True else self.modelb.hidden_size, n_class),
            nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size, timesteps, channel_x, h_x, w_x = x.shape
        conv_input = x.view(batch_size * timesteps, channel_x, h_x, w_x)
        conv_output = self.modela(conv_input)
        lstm_input = conv_output.view(batch_size, timesteps, -1)
        lstm_output = self.modelb(lstm_input)
        lstm_output = lstm_output[:, -1, :]
        output = self.output_layer(lstm_output)
        return output
```

Above is the NN that I use and the following code is used to train it.

```
modela = googleNet()
modelb = Lstm()
modelc = ConvLstm(modela,modelb).to(device)
## Loss and optimizer
learning_rate = 5e-4 #I picked this because it seems to be the most used by experts
load_model = True
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(modelc.parameters(), lr= learning_rate) #Adam seems to be the most popular for deep learning


modelc.train()
for epoch in range(100): #I decided to train the model for 100 epochs
    loss_ep = 0
    
    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(zip(features_train, labels_train)):
        data = data.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)
        ## Forward Pass
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        modelc.modelb.reset_hidden_state()
        scores = modelc(data)
        loss = criterion(scores,targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        loss_ep += loss.item()
    print(f"Loss in epoch {epoch} :::: {loss_ep/len(features_train)}")

    with torch.no_grad():
        num_correct = 0
        num_samples = 0
```

The cross entropy through the 100 epochs is at 2.301. What is going wrong?
I have read that the crossentropy includes softmax and I removed it from the output layer but the cross entropy still stays on the same value.

Comment: From the documentation of `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`, we find "The input is expected to contain raw, unnormalized scores for each class," but you apply softmax as the final step in the output of `modelc`. The duplicate thread specifically names this mistake as a common programming bug.

Comment: I have tried it by removing the softmax as well. When you say unormalised, you mean I shouldn't divide by 255 the pixels?

Comment: The *documentation* says "unnormalized scores," which means the network *output* (input to the loss) is expected to be unnormalized, in contrast to a probability (such as produced by softmax or a similar activation). Scaling the *input to the network* can make the optimization task easier, but is not related to the scale of the *inputs to the loss function.*

Comment: Thank you, so normalising the pixels shouldnt matter but I will try using the original values and let you know.

Comment: Doesnt make any difference

Comment: The duplicate has many more suggestions.